# google script add editors, raise invalid email

Tags: javascript, email, google-sheets, invalidation

Im using a google script to protect several sheets by adding editors to some ranges, most emails work fine but in some rare cases I get:
Invalid email:
But if I instead add the email manually it works without problem, so there isnt a problem with the email in reality. Does anyone know what is causing this and even better how to solve it?

```
var sheet = spread.getSheetByName(name)

sheet.getParent().addEditors(emails)
```

name is a string with the tab name and emails is a string[] with 1 or 2 emails

Comment: "Im using a google script..." - Can you add this code?

Comment: this is the relevant part of the code, in one place im also using sheet.getRange(<some range>).addEditors(emails) that one does work either.